# Multi-Monitor Support in LWJGL3

Tags: opengl, fullscreen, lwjgl, glfw, multiple-monitors

I have not been able to find out how to detect how many monitors are available for use in LWJGL3.

I have fullscreen working but i can only detect the primary monitor with GLFW.glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), this is fine when I am only using 1 monitor but when I have more than one monitor connected I would like fullscreen to work on my bigger monitor.

How would i go about doing this?

Comment: [`glfwGetMonitors()`](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFW.html#glfwGetMonitors--) not working for some reason?

Comment: @genpfault i am unable to find how to use glfwGetMonitors()